# Calculate width and height of a rectangle, given its diagonal and ratio

Tags: trigonometry

Well, I know, it's easy. We did it in class some time ago and I forgot it, I'm stupid because I can't figure it out:

E.g. I have a 32" TV with 16:9 ratio and I want to know its width and height.

I'd like to know the whole derivation so I can understand it (again) ...

Enlightenment, please! Thanks.

Comment: You use the Pythagorean theorem like so: your [diagonal's 32 inches](http://www.screenmath.com/) and you know the [aspect ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16:9) of your legs; that nets you $(16x)^2+(9x)^2=(32)^2$...

Comment: (After reading the Answer) Just saw your comment, thank you too! It's clear now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose that the unknown width and height are $x$ and $y$, and you’re given a diagonal $d$ and a ratio $m:n$ of width to height. That ratio means that the width is $\frac{m}{n}$ times the height, so you know that $x=\frac{m}{n}y$. You get a second relationship between $x$ and $y$ from the Pythagorean theorem: $x$, $y$, and $d$ are the lengths of the two legs and the hypotenuse of a right triangle, so $x^2+y^2=d^2$.

Now substitute $\frac{m}{n}y$ for $x$ in this second equation to get $\displaystyle\left(\frac{m}{n}y\right)^2 + y^2 = d^2$. Simplifying this, you get in turn: $$\frac{m^2}{n^2}y^2 + y^2 = d^2,$$ $$\left(\frac{m^2}{n^2}+1\right)y^2 = d^2,$$ $$\left(\frac{m^2+n^2}{n^2}\right)y^2=d^2,$$ and $$(m^2+n^2)y^2=d^2n^2.$$  Finally, solve for $y$: $\displaystyle y^2 = \frac{d^2n^2}{m^2+n^2}$, so $y=\displaystyle\frac{dn}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}$.
Once you have a numerical value for $y$, you can plug it into $x=\frac{m}{n}y$ to get a value for $x$.
(Or you can do that symbolically: $\displaystyle x=\frac{m}{n}\cdot \frac{dn}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}} =$  $\displaystyle\frac{dm}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}$.)

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much! I think I just was on the wrong path ... Looks so easy now.

Comment: A fiddle that implements these formulas to calculate width and height for arbitrary ratios and diagonals: https://jsfiddle.net/ypL7zd1a/2/ - Note: if the ratio is not given as `m=16` and `n=9`, but as decimal `1.777...`, use `n=1` and something like `m=1.777778`.

Answer (score 2):

$$w^2+h^2=32^2,\\\frac wh=\frac{16}{9}.$$

Then dividing by $h^2$,

$$\frac{w^2}{h^2}+1=\frac{16^2}{9^2}+1=\frac{32^2}{h^2},$$

$$h=\frac{32\cdot9}{\sqrt{16^2+9^2}},w=\frac{16}9h.$$

Answer (score -1):

Here is a code snippet from my gesture library. It is fully tested and calculates the width and height based upon and diagonal length and a width to height ration.

```
public void triggerFling(float dynamicFlingDistance, float width, float height) {

    float animationStartX = (int) matrixVals[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float animationStartY = (int) matrixVals[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float animationEndX = 0;
    float animationEndY = 0;

    if(dynamicFlingDistance == 0) {

        animationEndX = width;
        animationEndY = height;

    }
    else {

        if(width == 0 || height == 0) {

            if(width == 0 && height !=0) {

                animationEndX = (int) matrixVals[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                animationEndY = height;

            }
            else if(width != 0 && height ==0) {

                animationEndX = width;
                animationEndY = (int) matrixVals[Matrix.MTRANS_X];

            }
            else if(width == 0 && height == 0) {return;}//End if(width == 0 && height !=0)

        }
        else {

            if(height > 0) {

                animationEndY = (float) Math.sqrt((dynamicFlingDistance * dynamicFlingDistance) / (Math.pow((width / height), 2) + Math.pow((height / height), 2)));
                animationEndX = (animationEndY / (height / width));

            }
            else {

                animationEndY = (float) -Math.sqrt((dynamicFlingDistance * dynamicFlingDistance) / (Math.pow((width / height), 2) + Math.pow((height / height), 2)));
                animationEndX = (animationEndY / (height / width));

            }

        }//End if(width ==0 || height == 0)

    }//End if(dynamicFlingDistance == 0)

    translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(animationStartX, animationEndX, animationStartY, animationEndY);
    translateAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
    imageView.setAnimation(translateAnimation);
    imageView.getAnimation().setDuration(flingAnimationTime);
    imageView.startAnimation(translateAnimation);

    if(bounceBack == false) {

        final float animationEndXFinal = animationEndX;
        final float animationEndYFinal = animationEndY;

        new Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        matrixVals[Matrix.MTRANS_X] = animationEndXFinal;
                        matrixVals[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] = animationEndYFinal;

                        matrix.setValues(matrixVals);
                        imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                        imageView.invalidate();
                        imageView.requestLayout();

                    }
                }, flingAnimationTime);

    }//End if(bounceBack == false)

}
```